# Is every geodesic triangle contained in a surface?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic, convex-hulls

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional Riemannian manifold, $n \ge 3$.

> Let $T$ be a geodesic triangle in $M$. Does there exist a (smooth) $2$-dimensional embedded submanifold $S \subset M$ such that $T \subseteq S$?

I am OK with $S$ being a manifold with boundary or corners.

I thought of taking $S$ to be something like the convex hull of $T$, but this concept is a bit tricky for general Riemannian manifolds...

**Edit:**

The local case where $T$ is contained in some convex neighborhood of a point $p$ is sufficiently interesting for my purposes.

However, even when $p$ **is one of the vertices**, the following naive attempt seems suspicious:

Let $\triangle pqr$, suppose $q=\exp_p(v), r=\exp_p(w)$.

Then the image of $(t,s) \mapsto \exp_p\big(t(sv+(1-s)w)\big)$, where $0 \le t,s \le 1$ is a surface. But it is not clear to me whether the edge $qr$ is contained in this image. (I think this is not always the case, e.g. when $M$ is a sphere. In particular $s \mapsto \exp_p(sv+(1-s)w)$ does not coincide with $qr$).

Comment: If you have $\triangle PQR$, what about joining $P$ to the points of $\overline{QR}$ with (unique?) geodesics? Sounds suspicious but ... ?

Comment: @TedShifrin's good suggestion points out the type of ambient topological condition to eliminate: As stated, "no" because $M$ might be a punctured plane and the triangle might encircle the puncture. Are you willing to assume $M$ is contractible, say...? (Even with "contractible" I don't have a proof offhand -- not even sure if that's sufficient, but it does appear some global topological condition is necessary.)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thanks. I am not sure though that a puncture would necessarily be a problem. I didn't say $S$ needs to be compact. So for example, $M$ could be an Euclidean $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus {0}$.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that we need more: It would be nice if that exponentiated $2$-plane were totally geodesic. I know that if this is true for every point and every $2$-plane, then the manifold has constant curvature. Is the converse false?

Comment: @TedShifrin I am not sure. Your original idea seems very good to me, I will try to think some more about it.

Comment: Ah ... "geodesic triangle" caused me to read that the goal is to fill in with a union-of-geodesics triangle, and particularly that $T = \partial S$. <> I'm still misunderstanding, however: If this is local and $S$ only needs to be smooth, we may as well be considering a "topological triangle" $T$ (three smooth curves forming a cycle) contained in a ball $B$ in $\mathbf{R}^n$, and $M$ is effectively an open subset of $B$...? (If so, I'd be inclined to "drag an interval along $T$ to sweep out $S$.)

Comment: Wait a minute. We don’t need $T$ to be a geodesic triangle in $S$. Assuming there no holes, I think my original idea is fine. What Asaf suggested in his edit is different from my suggestion.

Comment: @TedShifrin I am confused. How can $T$ not be a geodesic triangle in $S$? Every "edge" of the triangle is a geodesic in the ambient manifold $M$, so it is also a geodesic in $S$, no? What am I missing here?

Comment: It's been so long now that I do not remember what I was thinking or not thinking. But I still say that your formula for exponentiating the triangle in the tangent plane at $p$ is different from joining $\overline{qr}$ with geodesics emanating from $p$.

Comment: Thanks, with that I agree.